# How can I find which is the most appropriate symbol (O, o, Ω, θ, ω) to describe f(n)∈__ g(n)?

Tags: analysis

When the given functions are $f(n)=n^{2+\sin (n \pi/2 )}$ and $g(n)=n^{5/3}$

I usually use limits but in this case the limit doesn't exist. How do I go about figuring out which notation to use? Is this an example of a convergent series?

Comment: what is "n5/3"?

Comment: In what sense do you usually use limits, and what limit is it that doesn't exist? There are no series here, convergent or otherwise.

Comment: @GFauxPas in the sense that for n congruent to 0 modulo 4, get $n^2$ which gives a subsequence $\frac{f(n_i)}{g(n_i)} \to \infty$, but another subsequence for 3 modulo 4 with a corresponding 0 limit.

Comment: Use $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ not just $\lim$.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're on the right track, but you haven't drawn the appropriate conclusion.  I take you to mean that you have determined the neither $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{f(n)\over g(n)}$$ nor $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{g(n)\over f(n)}$$ exists.  This is so, and the reason is that if $n$ is even, then $f(n)=n^2,$ but if $n\equiv1\pmod{4}$ then $f(n)=n^3.$

That means that we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{f(2n)\over g(2n)} = 0,$$ but $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{f(4n+1)\over g(4n+1)} = \infty$$

That means that none of the suggested notations is appropriate for all $n$ and $f$ and $g$ simply can't be compared using any of these notations.